# JSON nested folders when generating NFTs

Tags: javascript, json, config, cryptocurrency, nft

Looking to ask for assistance from someone who is much better at JSON than I. Running into an issue when generating an NFT collection using NFTCHEF's fork of Hashlips' art engine here on GitHub because it allows for nested folders: https://github.com/nftchef/art-engine

The file in question is the **[config.js](https://github.com/nftchef/art-engine/blob/nested-folder-structure/src/config.js)** file where it dictates how the files will be generated. Me being me, I of course chose the most difficult first attempt at this with nested folders.

I'd like my nested folders in /layers to also be rarities / traits themselves but cannot for the life of me figure out the proper way to format the code: https://github.com/nftchef/art-engine/blob/nested-folder-structure/src/config.js

Here is a picture of my folder structure.

[image]

The folders themselves in COLORS should be traits too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'll gladly send you a robot from the reserved pool when they're minted for helping out!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask].